# SQL Count and group duplicates

Tags: sql-server

Please advise the best way for solving my problem.

I have a problem figuring out how to count duplicates in table like below

```
Street       | City

avenue 123   | New York
avenue 123   | New York
avenue 20    | New York
avenue 35    | Chicago
avenue 12    | Chicago
avenue 123   | Chicago
avenue 12    | Chicago
avenue 12    | Chicago
```

I would like to have number of duplicate streets in the same City as result below?

result:

```
Street     | City | Duplicates

avenue 123 | New York | 2
avenue 12  | Chicago | 3
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY`, `COUNT` and `HAVING`:

```
 SELECT Street, City, COUNT(*)
 FROM yourtable
 GROUP BY Street, City
 HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

See it working online: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/65947/1)

Answer (score 5):

Try :

```
SELECT street, city, COUNT(*) AS duplicates
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY street, city
HAVING COUNT(*) >1
```

Remove `HAVING COUNT(*) > 1` if you want to display lines without duplicates as well.